# Allow both stateless and stateful session for the same URLs in Spring security

Tags: configuration, spring-security

I am trying to have 2 methods of access to my application.

1. via form-login
2. stateless - by passing specific arguments to the request that will go to the authentication provider and authenticate

The important thing is that if I have a link like the following: `http://localhost/application/action`, 
I will be able to access it if I already have a proper session (user sent a cookie) and am authenticated, or if I passed some parameters that are eventually authenticated.

I am able to pre authenticate like above by implementing a filter placed after `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter` and setting the context to a previously saved context.

However, I am unable to reuse a previous session causing it to recreate sessions all the time, and am unable to convert it into a stateless login.